# Uploading PDF obtained from API directly to s3 in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, amazon-s3

I am fetching a PDF report from a third party API, and I want to upload that PDF directly to the s3. When I do that, it uploads PDF to s3, but for some reason when I open that PDF in s3, all pages are blank. I am doing something wrong? My code is as below.

```
var report = reportInfo.body;
const params = {
   Key: 'report.pdf',
   Body: report,
   Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
   ContentType: 'application/pdf',
};
s3.upload(params, (err, res) => {
   if (err) {
        console.log(err, 'err');
   }
    console.log(res, 'res');
});
```

I am assigning the response from API to the **report** object. One part of the response is looking like this:

'%PDF-1.5\n%����\n1 0 obj<</Length 2872/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream\nx��\�n$�\r�����~�0� @�&1���>x�6�f����PU�U�a���mf���V�D�yHQ�փ��~$gF7�?���_/�����/��[�?��=�Ѓv���F?u��ǿS3�d��k��:O�����X�k���2�k���\t˿?�������XY�Ի��Ti-3�y��y�u3�Q~���E?�g����߈f_I4��'>>>�$�&����e��G���0�1Go�@M��&�*jҚ�YJ3�zmhz��0<�Q��n�۶�����i�\r5w�0�1���ѦO�5��SwM=�pm�����#f�>��q^g�*�j�J����}O�fi�xz&f�0�ǜ�^���yj���mm{�OM/B{z��%+��H�Ɣl4

I think that this is the plain PDF and that I can directly upload it to s3. Do I need to do something before uploading it?? Why it uploads only blank pages?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, can you please remove the unreadable context. Otherwise community will raise flag's against your question.

Comment: Where is `reportInfo.body` coming from? It should be a buffer, blob or a stream.

Comment: It is coming from REST API. Do you have any suggestion what to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF document should be fetched as `arraybuffer`.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const fetchAndUploadPDF = async () => {
  try {
    const pdf_document = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'url_of_the_report',
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/pdf',
      },
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    });
   
    await s3.upload({
      Key: 'file_name',
      Body: pdf_document.data,
      Bucket: 'bucket_name',
      ContentType: 'application/pdf',
      ACL: 'public-read',
    })
    .promise();

    console.log('PDF document successfully fetched and uploaded');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error.stack);
    throw(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all about encoding, In your scenario, file is the multipart file (pdf) that is passed to aws via a POST to the url.

- server gets a file with this byte -> 0010 (this will not be
  interpreted right, because a standard byte has 8 bits)
- so, we encode it in base 64 -> doesn't matter what result, decode it
  to get a standard byte -> 0000 0010 (now this is a standard byte and
  is interpreted right by aws)

For node.js encoding or decoding, you should refer this [doc](https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-node-js/).

Another configuration which need's to be done, the API Gateway settings must be properly configured to support binary data types.

**Path:** AWS Console --> API Gateway --> Settings --> multipart/form-data

[image]

Comment: So, what should I do with this data to make it right? To encode it to base 64 and then send to s3? Can you maybe type a small snippet as a suggestion? Tnx :D